# h264parse: broken/invalid nal Type

Tags: gstreamer, h.264, gstreamer-1.0

I am receiving h264 frames over a serial link, trying to play them with gstreamer. I set the caps to `gst_caps_from_string("video/x-h264")`, and it seems to accept them (if I use other caps, e.g. `application/x-rtp`, then the gstreamer log output complains about incompatible caps).

More specifically, I use the following elements: `appsrc ! h264parse ! rtph264pay`, and it seems like `h264parse` is the one not being happy.

When I pass (through `appsrc`) a frame that I get as a `byte[]` of length 8018, I get the following log output:

```
WARN h264parse gsth264parse.c:1496:gst_h264_parse_handle_frame:<h264parse0> broken/invalid nal Type: 6 SEI, Size: 12 will be dropped
WARN h264parse gsth264parse.c:1496:gst_h264_parse_handle_frame:<h264parse0> broken/invalid nal Type: 6 SEI, Size: 12 will be dropped
WARN h264parse gsth264parse.c:1496:gst_h264_parse_handle_frame:<h264parse0> broken/invalid nal Type: 1 Slice, Size: 7986 will be dropped
```

Note how those 3 WARN lines are similar, with the first two dropping size 12, and the last one dropping size `<my byte[] size> - 32`.

This is consistent over all the frames I send: it always complains twice about dropping 12, and then about dropping the length of the frame I pass minus 32.

Why could that be? Could it be related to my pipeline not receiving SPS/PPS data? I have been dumping the frames (`appsrc ! identity dump=true ! ...`), but I can't seem to find any frame that starts with `00 00 00 01 67` or `00 00 00 01 68`, though I'm not sure if that could create those warnings or not.

Comment: You probably need to share your stream - otherwise we would have to guess.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

From [the source code](https://gitlab.freedesktop.org/gstreamer/gstreamer/-/blob/main/subprojects/gst-plugins-bad/gst/videoparsers/gsth264parse.c#L1498), this message comes from:

```c
if (!gst_h264_parse_process_nal (h264parse, &nalu)) {
  GST_WARNING_OBJECT (h264parse,
      "broken/invalid nal Type: %d %s, Size: %u will be dropped",
      nalu.type, _nal_name (nalu.type), nalu.size);
  [...]
}
```

Where `gst_h264_parse_process_nal()`, for SEI frames, [returns FALSE](https://gitlab.freedesktop.org/gstreamer/gstreamer/-/blob/main/subprojects/gst-plugins-bad/gst/videoparsers/gsth264parse.c#L1026-1029) when:

```c
case GST_H264_NAL_SEI:
  /* expected state: got-sps */
  if (!GST_H264_PARSE_STATE_VALID (h264parse, GST_H264_PARSE_STATE_GOT_SPS))
    return FALSE;
```

With [`GST_H264_PARSE_STATE_VALID`](https://gitlab.freedesktop.org/gstreamer/gstreamer/-/blob/main/subprojects/gst-plugins-bad/gst/videoparsers/gsth264parse.c#L85-86) defined as:

```c
#define GST_H264_PARSE_STATE_VALID(parse, expected_state) \
  (((parse)->state & (expected_state)) == (expected_state))
```

It seems that this error comes when the state does not have `GST_H264_PARSE_STATE_GOT_SPS` set.

As a conclusion, the frames in the question above are dropped because the SPS data has not been received at this point.